# How to remove ol that contains specific number li?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am very new with html and css. So I really need help, here's my question.

How can i remove the ol tag that contain 3 li without class or id.

Here's the example :

```
<div class="text">
    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ol>

    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And here's the expected result :

```
<div class="text">
    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have a reason to not give it any class or id ? I am not sure you can do it without them

Comment: I think you can do it. First target the element `ol` and then you need to check that it has three children. and then change its visibility or display properties.  However, this Javascript script will be general in the targeted webpage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made a solution in JSBin where all ol tag containing exactly 3 li tag will be removed from DOM. Here is the link [solution](https://jsbin.com/wonujeqibo/1/edit?html,js,output)

And code that does the job:

```
$.each($('.text').find('ol'), function(i, item){
  if($(item).find('li').length == 3)
    {
      item.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please comment while down voting, then I could improve my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) jQuery method.

```
$('.text ol').filter(function() {

return $(this).children('li').length===3

}).remove();
```

```js
$('.text ol').filter(function() {

return $(this).children().length===3

}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
    <ol>
        <li>111</li>
        <li>2222</li>
        <li>3333</li>
    </ol>

    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ol>
   <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ol>   
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `ol` tag you want to remove is going to be first within the div, you can target it using first-child selector.

```
.text ol:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

If its position is going to vary, or you have more than one `ol` tag you want to remove, this won't work, and you'll need JavaScript.

```css
.text ol:first-child {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ol>

    <ol>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```